# Import XML on Wordpress installed whit xampp

Tags: xml, wordpress, xampp, local

i'm installed XAMPP over MacOS whit latest Wordpress version.

When I tried to import a XML file I recieved this error:

> This does not appear to be a WXR file, missing/invalid WXR version
>   number

I'm tried find a solution, the forums talks about "safe mode" on php.ini file of XAMPP, but SAFE MODE is deactivated and not works yet.

Could you help me?

Comment: Can you attach the XML file.

Comment: http://electronicadiccion.es/wpml-config.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is actually not a valid WordPress eXtended Rss (WXR) file. This means that you can't import it using `wp/wp-admin/import.php`

Actually, it is a configuration file of a theme or a plugin. So, you have to import it from the same theme/plugin.